# jquery focus on mobile safari does not work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I would like to focus on the next input field, after the user enters one number. Here are my inputs:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="id1" maxlength="1" id="1">
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="id2" maxlength="1" id="2">
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="id3" maxlength="1" id="3">
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="id4" maxlength="1" id="4">
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.in').keyup(function(){
        var i = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        if(i != 4){
            i = i + 1;
            s = 'id';
            s +=  i;
            $('input[name='+s+']').focus();
        }else{
            $('.confirm').show();
        }
      });
    });
```

On Firefox, IE etc. everything works fine. Only on Mobile Safari the focus does not work. I have to tap in the next input field to "reactivate" the number block for entering a value.

Any idea?

Greets & thx,
yab86

Comment: Mobile Safari only supports focus on touch events, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Focus() works on iOS. Maybe try with double quotes

```
$('input[name="'+s+'"]').focus();
```

or change the selector for keyup

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
```